# Propositional Logic Rosen textbook problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

**Q**: Consider the following premises:-

$1.$ What is good for corporations is good for the United States.
$2.$ What is good for the United States is good for you.
$3.$ What is good for the corporations is for you to buy lots of stuff.

What are the valid conclusions?

**MY work till now:**-

Corporation -> US
US -> You
Corporation -> Buy Stuff

How can I apply hypothetical syllogism to get the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more precise on what your propositions are: the statements "Corporation -> US US -> You Corporation -> Buy Stuff" don't make any sense.

Consider an object $x$. $C(x)$ is the statement "$x$ is good for corporations". $U(x)$ is the statement "$x$ is good for the United States". $Y(x)$ is the statement "$x$ is good for you". $b$ is the object (rather, action or idea) "you buying lots of things". Then we have can rewrite those three statements as:

1) $C(x)\implies U(x)$

2) $U(x)\implies Y(x)$

3) $C(b)$

Now remember that hypothetical syllogism means that if you have $P\implies Q$ and $Q\implies R$, then $P\implies R$. Using that and modus ponens, you should see your answer.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your response.Can you please tell me why have we written 3rd statement as C(B).I am able to get the answer.but not wble to understand this 3rd pont(how it came).

Comment: 3.What is good for the corporations is for you to buy lots of stuff.              So how does buying lot of stuff is good for corporations is implied by by this statement?Should't it be other way?

Comment: @rahulsharma This is a semantic issue: I read "What's good for corporations is for you to buy a lot of stuff" as "buying a lot of stuff is good for corporations". I suppose you could read it as "if something is good for corporations, then it's buying stuff" or as "the only thing good for corporations is buying lots of stuff" but you just need to assume that that's not how it's intended. The actual wording differs from the meaning, but by context, you should be able to understand what they mean.

Comment: Yeah I got that. Only thing disturbing me still is " FOR YOU"  in that statement by which I am implying that if something is good for corporation then it is for you to buy more stuff.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just typed it quickly and forgot that part. $b$ should be "for you to buy lots of stuff".

Comment: If that is the case then we don't need c part of the question as it is a valid conclusion from first two parts.

Comment: Actual answer has following statement

Comment: Answer :It is good for the United States if you buy lots of stuff. How this can be concluded?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the $c$ part. $C(b)$ is just a rephrasing of the third hypothesis you're given. You can't conclude it from the other parts. What you can conclude is $Y(b)$ due to hypothetical syllogism, which states that if $P\implies Q$ and $Q\implies R$, then $P\implies R$. Just apply that to the three statements we have.

Answer (score 1):

$1.$ What is good for the corporations is for you to buy lots of stuff. (Premise.)

$2.$ What is good for corporations is good for the United States. (Premise.)

$3.$ It is good for the United States if you buy lots of stuff. (Hypothetical Syllogism from $(2)$ and $(1)$.)

$4.$ What is good for the United States is good for you. (Premise.)

$5.$ It is good for you if you buy lots of stuff. (Hypothetical Syllogism from $(3)$ and $(4)$).

---

Hope I am correct and it helps.

Comment: See table page 72 for the rule *Hypothetical syllogism* : form $p \to q$ and $q \to r$ infer : $p \to r$. Premises 2. and 1. above are : $p \to q$ and $p \to r$; thus, *Hyp.syll* does not apply.